# The annotation "@Swagger\Annotations\Response" in method was never imported

Tags: symfony, swagger, fosrestbundle

I have a problem with fresh install of Swagger and FosRestBundle on Symfony 5 app.
I have this error :

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Swagger\Annotations\Response" in method ... was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.
```

There is my code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="api_ia", methods="GET")
 * @SWG\Response(
 *      response=200,
 *      description="Returns all informations based on image"
 *      @SWG\Schema(
 *          type="array"
 *      )
 * )
 * @SWG\Parameter(
 *      name="image"
 *      type="string"
 *      description="Photo of boiler label"
 * )
 * @SWG\Tag(name="IA")
 * @Security(name="Bearer")
 */
```

Has anyone ever had the problem? I did not modify my annotation file and I have imported Swagger\Annotations as SWG.

Comment: Can you share more details? Does removing that annotation also remove that error?

Comment: Error appear on each @SWG\* tags. If I remove all, errors disappear

Comment: Then please share more details, like the `use` statements within that class

Comment: `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`
`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;`
`use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Nelmio version.

Last version is 4.*, but in Symfony "current" page, we can read instructions for "Nelmio 3.x"

Read instructions here : https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Captain Nemo reply, with version 4.* of nelmio/api-doc-bundle it's `@OA` and not `@SWG`, with `use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;` !